# UISearchDisplayController doesn't work inside container view

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm aware that this topic has been touched on before, but as far as I'm aware, never with any discussion of a possible workaround suitable for my situation.

The problem is that `UISearchDisplayController` doesn't seem to work inside custom `ContainerView` controllers. I've put up a [sample project](https://github.com/blackp/TestContainedSearchingTableView/) that demonstrates this problem in the simplest case I could imagine.

Is there any alternative way of containing the view controllers so that the `UISearchDisplayController` can work as normal?

My suspicion is that the `UISearchDisplayController` doesn't have a reference to the correct `UINavigationController` (although I have tried setting it up programatically in `viewDidMoveToParentViewController`, where the `UINavigationController` should have been set).

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8166

Comment: blackp did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with an embedded `UITableViewController`. One of them was a missing `UISearchBar` after switching between `UIViewControllers` while the `UISearchDisplayController` is visible (I'm using `SWRevealViewController` to switch between `UIViewController`). This problem occurs only on iPads. It came out that the `UISearchBar` suddenly hides behind the `UINavigationBar`. Now I solved all my Problems with the following lines of code in the `UITableViewController` which is presented in a `UIContainerView`:

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return nil;
}
```

Those lines prevent the `UISearchDisplayController` to reach and change the `UINavigationController`. I also subclassed this method into "`MyContainerTableViewController`" class and use this class now for all embedded `UITableViewController`.